# Installing ArcGIS Python API with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, installation, arcgis-python-api

I am new to the world of ArcGIS and I come from a data science background. I recently installed ArcGIS Pro with a Single User license from my organization. I would like to use it with the Python API for deep learning.

Can anyone tell me how to get my setup properly working. I am confused as to how to login with the `GIS()` object in Python.

I would like to be able to perform tasks similar to this example: https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/land-cover-classification-using-unet/

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

For using ArcGIS API for Python, credentials have to be provided `gis = GIS("http://www.arcgis.com", "username", "password")`.

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS

gis = GIS("http://www.arcgis.com", "***", "***")
help(gis)
```

Information from `help(gis)`

```py
class GIS(builtins.object)
 |  GIS(url=None, username=None, password=None, key_file=None, cert_file=None, verify_cert=True, set_active=True, client_id=None, profile=None, **kwargs)
 |  
 |  .. _gis:
 |  
 |  A GIS is representative of a single ArcGIS Online organization or an ArcGIS Enterprise deployment. The GIS object
 |  provides helper objects to manage (search, create, retrieve) GIS resources such as content, users, and groups.
 |  
 |  Additionally, the GIS object has properties to query its state, which is accessible using the properties attribute.
 |  
 |  The GIS provides a mapping widget that can be used in the Jupyter Notebook environment for visualizing GIS content
 |  as well as the results of your analysis. To create a new map, call the map() method.
 |  
 |  The constructor constructs a GIS object given a url and user credentials to ArcGIS Online
 |  or an ArcGIS Enterprise Portal. User credentials can be passed in using username/password
 |  pair, or key_file/cert_file pair (in case of PKI). Supports built-in users, LDAP, PKI, Integrated Windows Authentication
 |  (using NTLM and Kerberos) and Anonymous access.
 |  
 |  If no url is provided, ArcGIS Online is used. If username/password
 |  or key/cert files are not provided, the currently logged-in user's credentials (IWA) or anonymous access is used.
 |  
 |  Persisted profiles for the GIS can be created by giving the GIS authorization credentials and
 |  specifying a profile name. The profile stores all of the authorization credentials (except the password) in the
 |  user's home directory in an unencrypted config file named .arcgisprofile. The profile securely stores the password
 |  in an O.S. specific password manager through the `keyring <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring>`_ python module.
 |  (Note: Linux systems may need additional software installed and configured for proper security) Once a profile has
 |  been saved, passing the profile parameter by itself uses the authorization credentials saved in the configuration
 |  file/password manager by that profile name. Multiple profiles can be created and used in parallel.
 |  
 |  See https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/working-with-different-authentication-schemes/ for examples.
 |  
 |  
 |  ================    ===============================================================
 |  **Argument**        **Description**
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  url                 Optional string. If URL is None, then the URL will be ArcGIS
 |                      Online.  This should be a web address to either a local Portal
 |                      or to ArcGIS Online in the form:
 |                      <scheme>://<fully_qualified_domain_name>/<web_adaptor> (Portal Example)
 |                      https://gis.example.com/portal
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  username            Optional string. The login user name (case-sensitive).
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  password            Optional string. If a username is provided, a password is
 |                      expected.  This is case-sensitive. If the password is not
 |                      provided, the user is prompted in the interactive dialog.
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  key_file            Optional string. The file path to a user's key certificate for PKI
 |                      authentication
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  cert_file           Optional string. The file path to a user's certificate file for PKI
 |                      authentication. If a PFX or P12 certificate is used, a password is required.
 |                      If a PEM file is used, the key_file is required.
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  verify_cert         Optional boolean. If a site has an invalid SSL certificate or is
 |                      being accessed via the IP or hostname instead of the name on the
 |                      certificate, set this value to False.  This will ensure that all
 |                      SSL certificate issues are ignored.
 |                      The default is True.
 |                      **Warning** Setting the value to False can be a security risk.
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  set_active          Optional boolean. The default is True.  If True, the GIS object
 |                      will be used as the default GIS object throughout the whole
 |                      scripting session.
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  client_id           Optional string. Used for OAuth authentication.  This is the
 |                      client ID value.
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  profile             Optional string. the name of the profile that the user wishes to use
 |                      to authenticate, if set, the identified profile will be used to login
 |                      to the specified GIS.
 |  ================    ===============================================================
 |  
 |  In addition to explicitly named parameters, the GIS object supports optional key word
 |  arguments:
 |  
 |  ================    ===============================================================
 |  **kwargs**          **Description**
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  proxy_host          Optional string. The host name of the proxy server used to allow HTTP/S
 |                      access in the network where the script is run.
 |  
 |                      ex: 127.0.0.1
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  proxy_port          Optional integer. The proxy host port.  The default is 80.
 |  ----------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |  token               Optional string. This is the Enterprise token for built-in
 |                      logins. This parameter is only honored if the username/password
 |                      is None and the security for the site uses BUILT-IN security.
 |  ================    ===============================================================
 |  
 |  
 |  
 |  
 |  .. code-block:: python
 |  
 |      # Usage Example 1: Anonymous Login to ArcGIS Online
 |  
 |      gis = GIS()
 |  
 |  .. code-block:: python
 |  
 |      # Usage Example 2: Built-in Login to ArcGIS Online
 |  
 |      gis = GIS(username="someuser", password="secret1234")
 |  
 |  .. code-block:: python
 |  
 |      # Usage Example 3: Built-in Login to ArcGIS Enterprise
 |  
 |      gis = GIS(url="http://pythonplayground.esri.com/portal",
 |            username="user1", password="password1")
 |  
 |  .. code-block:: python
 |  
 |      # Usage Example 4: Built-in Login to ArcGIS Enterprise, ignoring SSL errors
 |  
 |      gis = GIS(url="http://pythonplayground.esri.com/portal", username="user1",
 |                password="password1", verify_cert=False)
 |  
 |  .. code-block:: python
 |  
 |      # Usage Example 5: Anonymous ArcGIS Online Login with Proxy
 |  
 |      gis = GIS(proxy_host='127.0.0.1', proxy_port=8888)
 |  
 |  .. code-block:: python
 |  
 |      # Usage Example 6: PKI Login to ArcGIS Enterprise, using PKCS12 user certificate
 |  
 |      gis = GIS(url="https://pkienterprise.esri.com/portal",
 |                cert_file="C:\users\someuser\mycert.pfx", password="password1")
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, url=None, username=None, password=None, key_file=None, cert_file=None, verify_cert=True, set_active=True, client_id=None, profile=None, **kwargs)
 |      Constructs a GIS object given a url and user credentials to ArcGIS Online
 |      or an ArcGIS Portal. User credentials can be passed in using username/password
 |      pair, or key_file/cert_file pair (in case of PKI). Supports built-in users, LDAP,
 |      PKI, Integrated Windows Authentication (using NTLM and Kerberos) and Anonymous access.
 |      
 |      If no url is provided, ArcGIS Online is used. If username/password
 |      or key/cert files are not provided, logged in user credentials (IWA) or anonymous access is used.
 |      
 |      Persisted profiles for the GIS can be created by giving the GIS authorization credentials and
 |      specifying a profile name. The profile stores all of the authorization credentials (except the password) in the
 |      user's home directory in an unencrypted config file named .arcgisprofile. The profile securely stores the password
 |      in an O.S. specific password manager through the `keyring <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring>`_ python module.
 |      (Note: Linux systems may need additional software installed and configured for proper security) Once a profile has
 |      been saved, passing the profile parameter by itself uses the authorization credentials saved in the configuration
 |      file/password manager by that profile name. Multiple profiles can be created and used in parallel.
 |      
 |      If the GIS uses a secure (https) url, certificate verification is performed. If you are using self signed certificates
 |      in a testing environment and wish to disable certificate verification, you may specify verify_cert=False to disable
 |      certificate verification in the Python process. However, this should not be done in production environments and is
 |      strongly discouraged.
 |  
 |  __repr__(self)
 |      Return repr(self).
 |  
 |  __str__(self)
 |      Return str(self).
 |  
 |  map(self, location=None, zoomlevel=None, mode='2D', geocoder=None)
 |      Creates a map widget centered at the declared location with the specified
 |      zoom level. If an address is provided, it is geocoded
 |      using the GIS's configured geocoders and if a match is found, the geographic
 |      extent of the matched address is used as the map extent. If a zoomlevel is also
 |      provided, the map is centered at the matched address instead and the map is zoomed
 |      to the specified zoomlevel. See :class:`~arcgis.widgets` for more information.
 |      
 |      Note: The map widget is only supported within Jupyter Notebook.
 |      
 |      ==================     ====================================================================
 |      **Argument**           **Description**
 |      ------------------     --------------------------------------------------------------------
 |      location               Optional string. The address or lat-long tuple of where the map is to be centered.
 |      ------------------     --------------------------------------------------------------------
 |      zoomlevel              Optional integer. The desired zoom level.
 |      ------------------     --------------------------------------------------------------------
 |      mode                   Optional string of either '2D' or '3D' to specify map mode. Defaults to '2D'.
 |      ------------------     --------------------------------------------------------------------
 |      geocoder               Optional Geocoder. Allows users to specify a geocoder to find a given location.
 |      ==================     ====================================================================
 |      
 |      
 |      :return:
 |        The map widget (displayed in Jupyter Notebook when queried).
 |  
 |  update_properties(self, properties_dict)
 |      Updates the GIS's properties from those in properties_dict. This method can be useful
 |      for updating the utility services used by the GIS.
 |      
 |      
 |      ===============     ====================================================================
 |      **Argument**        **Description**
 |      ---------------     --------------------------------------------------------------------
 |      properties_dict     Required dictionary. A dictionary of just those properties and
 |                          values that are to be updated.
 |      ===============     ====================================================================
 |      
 |      :return:
 |         True if successfully updated, False if unsuccessful.
 |      
 |      
 |      .. note::
 |          For examples of the property names and key/values to use when updating utility services,
 |          refer to the Portal parameters section at https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/common-parameters.htm
 |      
 |      .. code-block:: python
 |      
 |          # Usage Example: Update the geocode service
 |      
 |          gis = GIS(profile='xyz')
 |          upd = {'geocodeService': [{
 |            "singleLineFieldName": "Single Line Input",
 |            "name": "AtlantaLocator",
 |            "url": "https://some.server.com/server/rest/services/GeoAnalytics/AtlantaLocator/GeocodeServer",
 |            "itemId": "abc6e1fc691542938917893c8944606d",
 |            "placeholder": "",
 |            "placefinding": "true",
 |            "batch": "true",
 |            "zoomScale": 10000}]}
 |      
 |          gis.update_properties(upd)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  content
 |      The resource manager for GIS content. See :class:`~arcgis.gis.ContentManager`.
 |  
 |  datastore
 |  
 |  groups
 |      The resource manager for GIS groups. See :class:`~arcgis.gis.GroupManager`.
 |  
 |  hub
 |      The resource manager for GIS hub. See :class:`~arcgis.apps.hub.Hub`.
 |  
 |  org_settings
 |      The portal settings resource is used to return a view of the 
 |      portal's configuration as seen by the current users, either 
 |      anonymous or logged in. Information returned by this resource 
 |      includes helper services, allowed redirect URIs, and the current 
 |      configuration for any access notices or information banners.
 |      
 |      ======================     ===============================================================
 |      **Parameters**             **Description**
 |      ----------------------     ---------------------------------------------------------------
 |      settings                   Required Dict.  A dictionary of the settings
 |      
 |                                  ==========================    =============================================
 |                                  **Fields**                    **Description**
 |                                  --------------------------    ---------------------------------------------
 |                                  anonymousAccessNotice         Dict. A JSON object representing a notice that is shown to your organization's anonymous users.
 |                                                                Ex: {'title': 'Anonymous Access Notice Title', 'text': 'Anonymous Access Notice Text', 'buttons': 'acceptAndDecline', 'enabled': True}
 |                                  --------------------------    ---------------------------------------------
 |                                  authenticatedAccessNotice     Dict. A JSON object representing a notice that is shown to your organization's authenticated users.
 |                                                                Ex: {'title': 'Authenticated Access Notice Title', 'text': 'Authenticated Access Notice Text', 'buttons': 'okOnly', 'enabled': True}
 |                                  --------------------------    ---------------------------------------------
 |                                  informationalBanner           Dict. A JSON object representing the informational banner that is shown at the top of your organization's page.
 |                                                                Ex: {'text': 'Header Text', 'bgColor': 'grey', 'fontColor': 'blue', 'enabled': True}
 |                                  --------------------------    ---------------------------------------------
 |                                  clearEmptyFields              Bool.  If True, any empty dictionary will be set to null.
 |                                  ==========================    =============================================
 |                                  
 |      ======================     ===============================================================
 |      
 |      :returns: Dictionary
 |  
 |  properties
 |      The properties of the GIS.
 |  
 |  url
 |      Readonly URL of the GIS you are connected to.
 |  
 |  users
 |      The resource manager for GIS users. See :class:`~arcgis.gis.UserManager`.
 |  
 |  version
 |      returns the GIS version number
```

---

**References:**

- [GitHub | ArcGIS API for Python](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api)

Comment: Not adding another answer because this is the answer, but a good note. you can add `GIS(url,un,pw,profile="random_profile_name")`. This will create a profile in your credential manager so after that all you need to do is `gis = GIS(profile="random_profile_name")`.

Comment: Thank you for a hint! Feel free extending my answer with your comment

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @Taras is correct in how you can authenticate and startup the GIS object within the ArcGIS Python API -- there is, however, many ways to get started.

See the [Working with different authentication schemes](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/working-with-different-authentication-schemes/) help topic.

In theory, you do not need to authenticate, you can start it up as an anonymous user to ArcGIS Online: `gis = GIS()`

However, as you said you want to make use of the Land Classification, that sample is using the Raster Analytics module, which requires a raster store. That means you need to be working against an on-premise ArcGIS Enterprise deployment. Based on that knowledge, you can make use of any of the authentication mechanisms listed in the help topic, as long as they apply to your particular Enterprise deployment.

Eg.

- Within Pro, where you've already connected: `gis = GIS("pro")`
- Using a built-in Enterprise account: `gis = GIS("https://portalname.domain.com/webadapter_name", "sharinguser", "password")`
- An Active Directory configured Enterprise: `gisldap = GIS("https://portalname.domain.com/webadapter_name", "AVWORLD\\Publisher", "password")`

....and so on

Comment: Thank you for clarity!

Answer (score 1):

See this page if you face issues with the installation process

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128385/how-to-install-arcgis-python-api-with-deep-learning-dependencies-geoai-deep

I am pasting the current installation commands From the documentation page [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/install-and-set-up/).

You need to first clone the default environment and activate the cloned environment, help page for the same is [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-conda.htm).
You can then run the following command in python command prompt to install ArcGIS Python API with deep learning dependencies
conda install -c esri -c fastai -c pytorch arcgis=1.8.2 scikit-image=0.15.0 pillow=6.2.2 libtiff=4.0.10 fastai=1.0.60 pytorch=1.4.0 torchvision=0.5.0 --no-pin